# Referring to Previous Statements in python

Tags: python

```
def bmicalculation(self):
        bmiheight=self.heightcm.get()
        print(bmiheight)
        bmiweight=self.weightkg.get()
        bmi= float((bmiweight)/((bmiheight / 100)**2))
        print(bmi)
        self.label1=Label(self.master,text='Your BMI is %.2f' % bmi).grid(row=5,column=0)

        if bmi <= 18.5:
            self.label2=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the underweight group.',fg='blue').grid(row=6,column=0)
            totalindex = 'underweight'
        elif bmi >18.5 and bmi <25:
            self.label3=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the healthy weight group.',fg='green').grid(row=6,column=0)
            totalindex = 'healthy'
        elif bmi >= 25 and bmi < 30:
            self.label4=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the overweight group.',fg='orange').grid(row=6,column=0)
            totalindex = 'overweight'
        elif bmi >=30:
            self.label5=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the obese group.',fg='red').grid(row=6,column=0)
            totalindex = 'obese'

        if bmi >0 and bmi <999999999999999999999:
            self.button6=Button(self.master,text="Store Data",fg='red',command=self.dynamic_data_entry).grid(row=8,column=0)


    def dynamic_data_entry(self):
        #this is what adds the data to the database. Bmi has to be changed to the value of bmi and weightclass has to be change to the weightclass
        timestamp = str(datetime.datetime.now().date())
        bodymassindex = '20'
        weightclass = str(totalindex)
        c.execute("INSERT INTO BMIStorage (timestamp, bodymassindex, weightclass) VALUES (?, ?, ?)",(timestamp, bodymassindex, weightclass))
        conn.commit()
```

I want to refer back to the term i created `bmi` in my second definition `def dynamic_data_entry`. How can i do this?

Also, how could i turn the weight groups given by the BMI into a string that I can then put into a database created by SQLite?

Comment: Is the indention correct? Is `dynamic_data_entry` a function *inside* `bmicalculation`?

Comment: You can't refer to a line of code. Just use variable references correctly

Answer (score 1):

Make `bmi` a class variable something like `self.bmi`. Same goes for `totalindex` as well.

```
bmi= float((bmiweight)/((bmiheight / 100)**2))
self.bmi = bmi

.
.
.
elif bmi >=30:
    self.label5=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the obese group.',fg='red').grid(row=6,column=0)
    totalindex = 'obese'

self.totalindex = totalindex
```

With these now you can access `self.bmi` and `self.totalindex` in your `dynamic_data_entry` method.

Answer (score 0):

If your second function `def dynamic_data_entry` is *inside* the `def bmicalculation(self)` function, the `bmi` variable should be accessible inside the function anyway.

If it's not, you need to pass it as a parameter to `def dynamic_data_entry`